# Create a new panel and display it every time I press the button

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to create a new panel each time I press a button. I've coded this function, which gets called inside my button:

```
public void createPanel()
{
    Panel createPanel = new Label();
    // set the properties for the panel
    createPanel.BackColor = Color.Black;
    createPanel.Size = new Size(420, 50);
    pnl1.Controls.Add(createPanel);
    createPanel.Show();
}
```

When I press the button the first time, the panel gets created and displayed, but when I press it the second time
the second panel is not getting added.

I want to achieve this :

[image]

Comment: You are adding each panel in exactly the same position, which means that they will be stacked on top of each other, and you will only be able to see the top-most one.   What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: The second panel is created on the *exact* location, with *exact* size and color the 1st panel has, so you see no difference

Comment: I edited my question, i want to create multiple panels inside my main panel that look like in the picture attached!

Comment: Use a FlowLayoutPanel as the container, so you don't need to determine its position, the layout is automatic.